# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array, android studio Java

Tags: java, android

I was trying to use intent to pass a string array to my next activity but I keep getting a null array reference error when I try to use the array in the next activity

This is the first activity

```
Button next;
next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(first_activity.this, second_activity.class);
intent.putExtra("strarr", strarr);
}
```

The next activity has the following code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] strarr = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strarr");
        TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        textview.setText("when did you take strarr[i]); 
// the error happens here when I try to reference I get the following message: 
"Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from null array"
```

Any help is appreciated, Thank You

Comment: I know it sounds kinda lame to ask, but did you miss the `startActivity(intent)` method after `intent.putExtra("strarr", strarr);` ?

Comment: Where and how is `strarr` defined in the first activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `getIntent()`, then add a null check:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if(intent != null && intent.getStringArrayExtra("strarr") != null){
        String[] strarr = intent.getStringArrayExtra("strarr");
        TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textView10);
        textview.setText("when did you take " + strarr[i]);
    }
}
```